# How to retrieve and render the uploaded image in JSP using JSTL tag?

Tags: html, servlets, jstl

Presently I am running the application from eclipse and have uploaded an image file in the location and I am passing this as a request attribute to the JSP user page.

**Issue (or) questions**

1. But when I am trying to access the file using the below File URL, Image not render ?
2. if it is deployed in the server how to access the file using the URL?
3. Do any changes that has to be done regarding accessing file location, before deploying the war in tomcat within the Linux Server ?

Thank you.

**xml context**

```
 <context-param>
 <param-name> tempfile.dir </param-name>
 <param-value> tmp_files </param-value>
 </context-param>
```

**File Location**

```
    F:\Techie\Servers_Apache\apache-tomcat-7.0.55\tmp_files\user_profile_pic.jpg
```

**servlet**

```
    request.setAttribute("user_profile_pic", uploadedImagePath);
```

**HTML tag in home.jsp**

```
    <img src= "${user_profile_pic}" alt="Mountain View" style="width:304px;height:228px">
```

.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) First of all upload/write the file to some location in server, which is publicly accessible, like ROOT or some folder inside ROOT.

2) As you wrote "But when I am trying to access the file using the below File URL, Image not render?", because it is a file URL, but browser only understands http URLs so it should be http URL, like `http://localhost:8080/tmp_files/user_profile_pic.jpg` etc.

3) You can make a properties or constants file in your code, and make variable like URL and PATH, to set http URL and file upload path respectively. In this way, you can set/change the values before deploying the war in tomcat within the Linux Server.